# Getting all combinations of key/value pairs in Python dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

This may be a silly question, but given the following dict:

```
combination_dict = {"one": [1, 2, 3], "two": [2, 3, 4], "three": [3, 4, 5]}
```

How would I achieve this list:

```
result_list = [{"one": [1, 2, 3], "two": [2, 3, 4]}, {"one": [1, 2, 3], "three": [3, 4, 5]}, {"two": [2, 3, 4], "three": [3, 4, 5]}]
```

In other words, I want all combinations of two key/value pairs in a dict without replacement, irrespective of order.

Comment: Why is there no `"two"`/`"three"` in your `result_list`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One solution is to use `itertools.combinations()`:

```
result_list = map(dict, itertools.combinations(
    combination_dict.iteritems(), 2))
```

**Edit**: Due to [popular demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905573/getting-all-combinations-of-key-value-pairs-in-python-dict/11905613#comment15849570_11905613), here a Python 3.x version:

```
result_list = list(map(dict, itertools.combinations(
    combination_dict.items(), 2)))
```

Comment: +1. Unless there's specifically a reason to do otherwise, I lean towards making code more portable between python 2 and 3. I'd use `dict.items()` _unless_ there is a memory issue with.

Comment: @JoelCornett If you are considering 3.x then you would also have to convert the `map` object to a `list` so it would be better to leave this as a note

Comment: @JoelCornett: Yeah, fine.  I guess if I had used `items()` instead of `iteritems()`, someone would have commented that this wastes memory.  (Honestly, if the dictionary is that large that it is a problem to take a copy of pointers to all keys and values, you certainly don't want to create all combinations of two items, which uses O(n²) additional space.)

Comment: @JollyJumper: You're right :p. All the same, it may be useful to include a 3.x version below your 2.x one, just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the solution by @JollyJumper for readability although this one performs faster

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> d = {"one": [1, 2, 3], "two": [2, 3, 4], "three": [3, 4, 5]}
>>> [{j: d[j] for j in i} for i in combinations(d, 2)]
[{'three': [3, 4, 5], 'two': [2, 3, 4]}, {'three': [3, 4, 5], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}, {'two': [2, 3, 4], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}]
```

Timings:

```
>python -m timeit -s "d = {'three': [3, 4, 5], 'two': [2, 3, 4], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}; from itertools import combinations" "map(dict, combinations(d.iteritems(), 2))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.27 usec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "d = {'three': [3, 4, 5], 'two': [2, 3, 4], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}; from itertools import combinations" "[{j: d[j] for j in i} for i in combinations(d, 2)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.92 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
combination_dict = {"one": [1, 2, 3], "two": [2, 3, 4], "three": [3, 4, 5]}
lis=[]
for i in range(1,len(combination_dict)):
    for x in combinations(combination_dict,i):
        dic={z:combination_dict[z] for z in x}
        lis.append(dic)
print lis
```

**output:**

```
[{'three': [3, 4, 5]}, {'two': [2, 3, 4]}, {'one': [1, 2, 3]}, {'three': [3, 4, 5], 'two': [2, 3, 4]}, {'three': [3, 4, 5], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}, {'two': [2, 3, 4], 'one': [1, 2, 3]}]
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe this would get you what you need.

```
result list = [{combination_dict['one','two'],combination_dict['one','three']}]
```

I found this tutorial to be very helpful:

http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/python-tutorial-dictionaries-key-value-pair-maps-basics/