# need to get dictionary that is a list of other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have no clue where to start to retrieve all of the dictionaries.

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries. A dictionary is a Python object. If you want to extract the first of these objects then  you will access the object in the first position of your list. Do this by, `gradebook[0]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all combinations of key/value pairs in Python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905573/getting-all-combinations-of-key-value-pairs-in-python-dict)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
gradebook=[{"name": "Samantha", "homework": 95, "test": 92, "exam": 100},{"name": "john", "homework": 55, "test": 11, "exam": 12},{"name": "shane", "homework": 5, "test": 1, "exam": 2}]

#if you want to access first student entire dict then

print(gradebook[0])

#if you want to access any student entire dict by name

name='john'
for i in gradebook:
    for index_no,value in i.items():
        if value==name:
            print(i)
```

output :

```
{'exam': 100, 'test': 92, 'name': 'Samantha', 'homework': 95}
{'exam': 12, 'test': 11, 'name': 'john', 'homework': 55}
```