# How to create dictionaries based on a list of values associated with keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a dictionary, params_dict, that I'm using to generate the query parameters for a url string using urllib request and parse. It works fine and when I tweak the parameters, I just .copy() the dict and use .update() to update the the relevant key/value pair(s).

```
params_dict = {'mt':0, 'age':1, 'sex':1, 'color':red, 'year':2008, 'division':&}
```

However, this seems clunky. Some key-value pairs remain the same like for the 'mt', 'division', but for other keys the values can come from a list like:

```
params_dict = {'mt':0, 'age':[1,2,3,4,5,6] 'sex':1, 'color':['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'], 'year':[2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014], 'division':&}
```

What I'd like to to do is to generate all combinations of the parameters i need to generate the query portion of the url and dump it into a list and then use a for loop to request the url links in that list.

So some of the combinations would look like:

```
combo1_dict = {'mt':0, 'age':1, 'sex':1, 'color':'green', 'year':2008, 'division':&}
combo2_dict = {'mt':0, 'age':1 'sex':1, 'color':'blue', 'year':2008, 'division':&}
```

....and so forth. I've tried playing with itertools.combinations ([Getting all combinations of key/value pairs in Python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905573/getting-all-combinations-of-key-value-pairs-in-python-dict)), but I can't quite figure it out.

Any advice/guidance would be very much appreciated!!!!

Comment: What is your use-case? Passing a list of multiple ages (represented in a query string as `?age=1&age=2`) is a valid and common approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close. [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is for getting all possible combinations of items in a single list. However, you want all possible combinations of items from multiple lists, such that each list contributes exactly one item.

The solution is [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Roughly equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, `product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`.

So for your urllib example:

```
import itertools

ages = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #all possible ages
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'] #all possible colors
years = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014] #all possible years

param_dicts = []
for age, color, years in itertools.product(ages,colors,years):
    #for all possible combinations of ages, colors, and years
    param_dicts.append({'mt':0, 'age':age, 'sex':1, 'color':color, 'year':year, 'division':&})
```

or as a list comprehension:

```
param_dicts = [{'mt':0, 'age':age, 'sex':1, 'color':color, 'year':year, 'division':&} for age, color, years in itertools.product(ages,colors,years)]
```