# Python Dictionary How to create combinations of list items?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has value as a list.

```
thisdict = {  'G1' : [10,20],
              'G2' : [12,13]

}
```

I want to create new dictionary with  all possible 4 combinations.

C1 :[10,12]

C2 :[10,13]

C3 :[20,12]

C4 :[20,13]

How do I create that ?

Comment: Take a look at the `intertools` module, it has functions for getting combinations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```
from itertools import product

d = {}
offset = 1
for e in product(thisdict['G1'], thisdict['G2']):
    d[f'C{offset}'] = list(e)
    offset += 1
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'C1': [10, 12], 'C2': [10, 13], 'C3': [20, 12], 'C4': [20, 13]}
```

Comment: that actually should work , and one more thing if I want it as 
{'C1': [G1:10,  G2:12], 
'C2': [G1:10, G2:13], 
'C3': [G1:20, G2:12], 
'C4': [G1:20, G2:13]}

how should I do that ?

Comment: Change the assignment statement to `d[f'C{offset}'] = [f'G1:{e[0]}', f'G2:{e[1]}']`

Comment: that is right but is there way to put a loop on e[0] such that when dictionary has G1,G2,G3  it should automatically take care of it instead of writing  d[f'C{offset}'] = [f'G1:{e[0]}', f'G2:{e[1]}' , f'G2:{e[2]}']

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please give an example of what you're looking for? Pseudocode is fine.

Comment: Do specify the output as well.

Comment: So suppose genes increases in the dictionary like G1,G2,G3 so in your code we have to manually take care of that . I searched online and found out that product(thisdict['G1'], thisdict['G2']) can be replaced with product(*thisdict.values()) . Now in the same way , I want to know how can I change d[f'C{offset}'] = [f'G1:{e[0]}', f'G2:{e[1]}']  statement in the code so that it becomes general .

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for: itertools.combinations()

This might help too
[Getting all combinations of key/value pairs in Python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905573/getting-all-combinations-of-key-value-pairs-in-python-dict)

Comment: Actually no. I want to select only 1 value from 1 key and 2nd value from 2nd key. In that way I should have 4 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

As other stated, you can use `itertools.product` for this.

But you have just two lists, you can also just use two `for` loops:

```
> d = { f'C{i+1}': {'G1':g1e, 'G2':g2e}
      for i, (g1e, g2e) in
      enumerate((g1e, g2e) for g1e in thisdict['G1']
                           for g2e in thisdict['G2']) }
> d
{'C1': {'G1': 10, 'G2': 12},
 'C2': {'G1': 10, 'G2': 13},
 'C3': {'G1': 20, 'G2': 12},
 'C4': {'G1': 20, 'G2': 13}}
```

NB: I used the format requested in the comment to another answer.